# How to add relative path for srcs :[] in android.bp file

Tags: android, android-soong

I m using androidmk tool to convert Android.mk files to Android.bp at many places we have Android.mk chanining so it produces relative path for srcs:[], but its not working with Android.bp build.
Throwing error :
Path is outside directory: ../../XX.cpp

srcs:[
      "example1.cpp"
      "../../example2.cpp"  --- error for this file
]

Path is outside directory:"../../example2.cpp"

Answer (score 2):

This is not allowed in `Soong`. You have to move your `Android.bp` to a common parent folder so that it looks like this.

```
srcs: ["a/b/example1.cpp", "example2.cpp"]
```

Comment: Is there any other workaround ... since i have a lot of Android.mk files chained ?? It will take some efforts for me to realign allow the Android.mk files ??

Comment: You could try creating symlinks of your sources in the `Android.bp` folder or a subfolder of it if you don't mind willingly bypass `Soong` checks: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/refs/heads/pie-release/android/paths_test.go#61

Answer (score 2):

We don't allow references outside of the current directory and its subdirectories in Soong

There are two ways to overcome to resolve the above issue.

- defining filegroup modules that can be used in the src[s] fields via ":myfilegroup".

Define the below code in parent or root dir:

```
    filegroup {
    name: "commaonfile",
    srcs: ["common/**/*.cpp"],
}
```

And use the filegroup in inner dirs where wants to use like below code:

```
cc_binary {
name: "abc"
srcs: [
       "src/a/b/abc.cpp"
       ":commaonfile"
      ],
}
```

- shift all the Android.bp to parent dir and make it work.